# How to create table dynamically using count and JSTL ForEach

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I want to create a dynamic table accepting book attributes when it has provided the no. of books to be entered on the previous page. 
But I am not getting anything.

This is my code:

```
<table>
<c:forEach begin="1" end= "${ no }" step="1" varStatus="loopCounter">
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' name="isbn" placeholder="ISBN">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Authors" placeholder="Author">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Version" placeholder="Version">
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

${no} is the count of number of books I want to enter.
I am new here. Sorry if the title is not clear. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not getting anything because you're not iterating your list of books. Also, you're only printing lots of `<input type="text" />` on each iteration. Your code should look like this (assuming that your list of books is `lstBooks` and it's already initialized):

```
<table>
    <!-- here should go some titles... -->
    <tr>
        <th>ISBN</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Authors</th>
        <th>Version</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach begin="1" end= "${ no }" step="1" varStatus="loopCounter"
        value="${lstBooks}" var="book">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.isbn}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.title}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.authors}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.version}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

---

After understanding your problem based on comments, make sure the `${no}` variable is available at `request.getAttribute("no")`. You can test this using a scriptlet (but this is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197/)) or just using `<c:out value="${no}" />`.

Note that as I've said, the variable should be accesible through `request.getAttribute`, do not confuse it with `request.getParameter`.

By the way, you can set a variable if you know which could be it's value like this:

```
<c:set var="no" value="10" />
```

And then you can access to it using `${no}`.

More info: [JSTL Core  Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm)

Comment: i am trying to take input. That's why I have <input>. actually all examples present are only iteration based. is it possible to work as normal loop?? ex: printing one line 10 times

Comment: You want inputs with the values of your books in there?

Comment: yes. I want to create this dynamic form which accepts no of books from the user. It takes input as no of books from previous page. Sorry for less info.

Comment: Well, assuming this `${no}` variable comes from previous request as an attribute, your `<c:forEach>` should work as a `for-loop`. Maybe the problem you have is that the `${no}` variable has `null` or `0` value. You can make a simple test by adding `<c:out value="${no}" />` before the loop.

Comment: I think I found out the issue.                                       <%
int s = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("no"));
System.out.println(s);
%>                                                                                   I found out that the ${no} is not working. I tried {pageScope.no} but no luck. Now the "s" variable is working for me. THank you so much for help. Just wanted to use ${} for number, No worries. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

*Suppose You have given a List of map `List<Map<String, Object>>` underEmployees*

```
<caption>Emplyess Under You</caption>
<tr>
    <th>Employee Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Designation
</tr>
<c:forEach  var="record"  items="${underEmployees}" > 
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="entry" items= "${record}">
            <th><c:out value="${entry.value}"></c:out></th>
        </c:forEach>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${students }" var="student">
    <tr>
      <td>${student.firstName}</td>
      <td>${student.lastName }</td>
      <td>${student.age }</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```