# Accessing JSTL variable in Scriplet

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Hi i want to use jstl variable in scriplet i I want to print a "hello" when num==3 it tried get the following code but value of i remains zero.

I want get the value of `num` and increment it by 1 then check if `num==3` then print hello once condition is true reassign value again to zero.

```
<c:set var="num" value="0"></c:set>
                <c:forEach items="${requestScope.Products}" var="emp" begin="0" end="${size}" >

                    <c:if test="${num==3}">
                    <h1>hello</h1>

                    </c:if>
                    <%! int var=0;%>
                    <% var=Integer.parseInt(pageContext.getAttribute("num").toString());%>
                <%

                System.out.println(var);

                     var=var+1;%>
                    <h2><c:out value="${num}"></c:out></h2>


                <td width="100">
                    <img src="images/${emp.image}" width="100" height="100"/>
                    Title<p>${emp.title}</p>
                    Price<p>${emp.price}</p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Buy No" class="bluebutton"/>
                </c:forEach>
```

---

**EDIT**

I want to display max 3 records in a row like if i 15 records then there will be 5 rows,. and with in row there will be 3 columns problem is when i write like this

```
<tr> <td>${tile}</td> <td>price<td>
```

in a for loop it shows first record 3 times but i want new record in each column.

Here is my modified code:

```
<% int size=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("size").toString());

    %>
    <h1><%= size%></h1>
    <table border="1" width="50%">


                <tr >
                  <c:set var="num" value="0"></c:set>
                  <c:forEach items="${requestScope.Products}" var="emp" begin="0" end="${size}" varStatus="loop">

                 <c:choose>
                  <c:when test="${num==3}">
                  <tr>

                  </tr>
                       <c:set var="num" value="0"></c:set>
                        </c:when>
                       <c:otherwise>
                            <td width="100">
                        <img src="images/${emp.image}" width="100" height="100"/>
                        Title<p>${emp.title}</p>
                        Price<p>${emp.price}</p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Buy No" class="bluebutton"/>
                 </td>
                       </c:otherwise>
                       </c:choose>
                        <c:set var="num" value="${num + 1}" />
                        <h2><c:out value="${num}"></c:out></h2>
                  </c:forEach>

                </tr>


        </table>
```

Comment: **"hello" when i==3** where is `i` in your code?

Comment: What is the purpose if  `int var` in your code?

Comment: through var i am getting value of num which is jstl variable

Comment: What is expected output in your case when `num` is zero as shown in your code

Comment: Its always zero `<c:set var="num" value="0"></c:set>` You are not modifying it any where in your code

Comment: You have assigned it to another int variable `var` and incrementing `var` will not impact the value of `num` as happen in JAVA as well.

Comment: i want get the value of num and increment it by 1 then check if num==3 then print hello once condition is true reassgin value again to zero

Comment: OK Let me share you code

Comment: actually i want to display records in a grid view. i am developing a ecommerce site where i want to display items in form of grid as on other sites so can you help in that case

Comment: Where did you stuck? simply use `<table>`

Comment: i am confused with for loop

Comment: Look at [How to create table dynamically using count and JSTL ForEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783572/how-to-create-table-dynamically-using-count-and-jstl-foreach) Find more on Google.

Comment: i want to display max 3 records in a row like if i 15 records then there will be 5 rows,. and with in row there will be 3 columns problem is when i write like this  
<tr>
<td>${tile}</td>
<td>price<td>
in a for loop it shows first record 3 times but i want new record in each column

Comment: Let me share you a sample code.

Comment: I TRIED THIS BUT IT SHOWS 3 RECORDS IN 1ST ROW THEN 2 RECORDS EACH ROW

Comment: Just copy my sample code. It works that's why I have sharead screenshots as well.

Comment: Fit your code in my sample code. **Don't modify your question** Otherwise there will be no meaning of my last answer. Instead use EDIT section. Please revert back your post with new Edits.

Comment: I have already shared you a link. Just do some exercise with sample code then apply your knowledge in your actual code.

Comment: Look at my post and update `Fit your actual code here` part only.

Comment: in your code it shows 3 records in first row but after it shows only 2 records per row

Comment: Post your modified code. Change it in EDIT section only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I want get the value of num and increment it by 1 then check if num==3 then print hello once condition is true reassgin value again to zero**

Read inline comments for more info.

Sample code: (Modify it as per your requirement)

```
<c:set var="num" value="0"></c:set> <!-- initial value -->
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.Products}" var="emp">

    <c:if test="${num==3}">
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <c:set var="num" value="0"></c:set> <!-- re-initialize value -->
    </c:if>
    <c:set var="num" value="${num + 1}" /> <!-- increment value -->
    <h2>
        <c:out value="${num}"></c:out>
    </h2>

</c:forEach>
```

---

**EDIT**

I want to display max 3 records in a row like if i 15 records then there will be 5 rows,. and with in row there will be 3 columns.

```
<c:set var="Products" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15" scope="request"/>

<c:set var="beginTR" value="true" /> <!-- to check for tr start -->
<table border="1">
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.Products}" var="emp"
        varStatus="status">

        <c:if test="${status.index%3==0}"> <!-- check for columns no -->
            <c:if test="${beginTR}">
                <tr>
                    <c:set var="beginTR" value="false" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${!beginTR}">
                </tr>
                <c:set var="beginTR" value="true" />
            </c:if>
        </c:if>
        <td>
              <c:out value="${emp}"></c:out> <!-- Fit your actual code here -->
        </td>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what is the diffrence between c:if and c :when

Comment: Find the answer here [jstl_core_choose_tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm)

Comment: You can use `c :when` along with `c : otherwise` Just like `if-else` in JAVA

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your support

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach items="${Products}" var="emp" begin="0" end="${size}" varStatus="status" >
   <c:if test="${status.index==3}">
      <h1>hello</h1>
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```